# Как сделать монеты за лайки и репосты?

Tags: node.js, php, ios, vkontakte-api, facebook-api

Есть iOS приложение и бекенд. Я делаю бекенд. Задача — сделать механизм, для того, чтобы за лайки и репосты к приложению давались монеты. Сети: мэйл, вк, фб, твиттер. Что где можно прочитать о том, как такую штуку сделать?

Comment: Про практику не скажу, теорию могу:
лайки же ставятся из приложения? значит когда нажимается на лайк от сервера приходит ответ success или fail, ну и соответственно ответам и давать/недавать. Посмотрите в методах библиотек, которые будете использовать для лайканья, стопудово там это есть.

Comment: То есть, это задача клиента, а не бэкенда?

Comment: Делали такое - клиент после каждого лайка отправлял идентификатор соц сети, что сделал, на каком объекте и зашифрованный ключ, чтобы исключить мошенничество. Все равботало отлично, монетки капали когда нужно

Answer (score 1):

Делал только для ВК.

Новый пост с вашим содержанием создаётся с клиента, с помощью [JS SDK](https://vk.com/dev/Javascript_SDK). Ф-ии **`api()`** помимо метода ([`wall.post`](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post)) можно дать ф-ю `callback`, которая ajax запросом отправит вам на сервер id только что сделанного юзером (ре)поста. С сервера нужно проверить, есть ли такой пост и содержит ли нужный текст. Всё ок — можно наградить юзера. id поста хорошо бы сохранить и перепроверить, скажем, через день, не стёрт ли уже.

Монеты — только у.е. вашего приложения, запись в вашей БД. Начислять юзерам ВКонтактовские «голоса» невозможно.

См. также [правила ВК](https://vk.com/dev/rules) – «слишком успешные» вирусные приложения быстро банят. Делал как-то такие пиратские репосты-конкурсы "выиграй ойфон", жили дня три.

Comment: Да, я и имел в виду свои монеты. Проверять id, я так понимаю, не обязательно?

Comment: И еще вопрос: у меня клиент на iOS, а не в вебе. Соответственно, я так понимаю, что делать все это должен iOS-программист? За исключением бд, конечно

Comment: Проверять id поста обязательно: иначе кто-то быстро догадается просто слать вам якобы id, зарабатывая ваши монеты. 

id ВК-юзера можно и не проверять: вам же важно, чтобы пост был сделан, а по посту однозначно идентифицируется его автор.

На сервере приём данных о новом посте и его проверка. Клиентскую часть разумеется, делает iOS разработчик.